# Sharing data in Real Time between two C++ projects

Tags: c++, real-time, shared-memory

I have a MFC project that acquire in real time some data and i want to share them (always in real time) with a second project that act as a server and send them to another program (the client). The second project is a big project with a lot of headers and dependecies.

I'm not very expert of this, so i ask you to know if a shared memory could be a good solution or if there is a way to integrate the two project and so to start the server directly from the MFC project.

Thanks for your helping.

Comment: Shared memory is **a** way to accomplish this, but there is no way to tell if it it she best way or even a good way from the information provided.

Comment: If you *always* want to share the data in real time, you will never need to keep the data around for later use.  So there is no need for shared memory.  Use sockets (or some other suitable mechanism) to pass the data from one component to the next.

Comment: @SidS Actually a socket is used to connect the second project (server) and the program (client). It's possibile for the second project being at the same time server and client of the MFC project that send the data?